# Django web server removing query string from browser URL

Tags: python, django

I'm running the Django development web server (`python manage.py runserver`), and when I add a query string to a URL which is served by a view, the query string is removed from the URL in the browser.  For example, when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?test=y`, the browser URL shows `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.  The log, though shows the GET parameter:

```
[25/Aug/2018 11:18:41] "GET /?test=y HTTP/1.1" 200 8517
```

Here is my view:

```
def main_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return login(request)
  elif request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect_user_main_page(request)
  else:
    return render(request, 'main_page2.html', {
      'next': request.GET.get('next'),
      })
```

and my URL:

```
  url(r'^$', main_page, name="main_page"),
```

The `else:` path is taken in this scenario.  When I print `request.GET`, I see the query string.

I observe this behavior on all browsers.

I also observe this behavior when I run the Django app behind Nginx and uWSGI.

I'm using Django 1.11.4.

Comment: Can you post here your URL for the home page?

Comment: No.  Are there any logs I can provide?

Comment: You need to show your URLs and views.

Comment: Ok, I thought he meant the URL of website.

Comment: No. I meant exactly what @DanielRoseman said.

Answer (score 0):

This issue wasn't related to Django.

I had the following JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  history.pushState(document.title, null, window.location.pathname);
}
```

This replaced the browser's URL with `window.location.pathname`, which does not have the query string.  I used `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: This doesn't apply to me but I have the same problem as OP. Any other ideas?